# Responsive CSS - Target 1024 x 768 Screen Size Only

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have built a responsive site, Works fine on all screen sizes barring the 1024 x 768 (Tablet Landscape)

I am looking for specific CSS (or am open for JS) to target a 1024 x 768 screen.

Comment: out of my curiosity: why do you need a different css for the same resolution on different devices?

Comment: Add a more specific sized breakpoint to your media stylesheets, what are your breakpoints currently?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I am working on a show and hide logic for some responsive images. The 1024 isnt quite matching up to the desktop view.

Comment: I don't understand in fact the desktop view has to be the default styles and `media queries` for lower devices...

Comment: Is your question about the styles applied for tablet landscape, which gets css of desktop?

Comment: Nice article - [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use for desktop:

```
@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px){
    // your code
}
```

Use for tablet:

```
@media (min-device-width:769px) and (max-device-width:1024px){
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media Query Like this

```
@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    //css stuffs here
}
```

This is the Way if you want Tablet landscape