# Flexbox: Layout with rowspan

Tags: css, flexbox

My HTML is similar to the following example

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="a">a</div>
 <div id="b">b</div>
 <div id="c">c</div>
 <div id="d">d</div>
</div>
```

On desktop I'd like the divs to display next to each other which is of course trivial.

On mobile I'd like have table-like layout with similar to the following

[image]

b, c and d have flexible height so a would have to adjust to that.

Is that possible to do without wrapping b,c and d in a separate div?

Comment: It will be easier if you wrap in a separate div. Why not use that?

Comment: You may have to define separate mobile and desktop style sheets using @media property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162094/responsive-css-target-1024-x-768-screen-size-only Declaring separate style sheets could then implement the flex box model differently for the desired effects. Downside, you have to choose a hard-set dimension for layout change.

Comment: I don't mind using separate style sheets with the @media property. The problem is that I have just no idea at all how to align the divs as I would like to on mobile without wraping b, c and d in a separate div.
Wrapping them in a separate div is of course possible but not really required from semantic perspective

Comment: I think this is the best approach as you are explicitly defining separate layouts for different dimensions.

Comment: Whenever I work on Flex-box model I find that this reference is essential to me, has a nice visual representation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thanks Matt. I've looked at that resource before and I'm actually using the tips from there for my horizontal Desktop layout.  Doing just columns or just rows is super easy with flexbox. What I can't figure out though is how to get the kind of table-like layout that I've described above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this **entirely** with `flexbox`...of course you're going to need to decide on a width for the first div at smaller viewport sizes but I assume that you have that in mind already ready for the required media query.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#wrapper div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
#a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  #a {
    height: auto;
    flex-grow: none;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d">d</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OVvVgr)

Answer (score 0):

Use only flexbox when it's needed: on desktop version:

```css
*    { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; }
#a   { background: tomato; }
#b   { background: forestgreen; }
#c   { background: dodgerblue; }
#d   { background: orange; }

#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper > div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}
#wrapper > #a {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    #wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }
    #wrapper > div {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #wrapper > #a {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl.</div>
  <div id="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh.</div>
  <div id="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius.</div>
  <div id="d">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure your answer accounts for the divs laying aside from each other on full screen desktop.

Comment: OP already done the desktop version, isn't he asking for a mobile solution?

Comment: this relies on a fixed eight for #a though. The data in b,c and d is somewhat flexible so the height can vary.

Comment: Not sure, I think they are looking for both but maybe I'm interpreting the question wrong.

Comment: @MarcS I updated my answer to show you how to do it with flexible divs (still not using flexbox for mobile version).